# Regex Non Greedy Matching across newlines

Tags: ruby, regex, elixir

I am trying to match the following:

```
str = "---title: Some Title\ndate: 01/01/2012---\n\nSome other stuff---\n\n"
```

And I would like to get:

```
"title: Some Title\ndate: 01/01/2012"
```

So, the regex I came up with was:

```
~r/---(.+)---(.+)/s
```

It's unfortunately, being greed and matching:

```
"title: Some Title\ndate: 01/01/2012---\n\nSome other stuff"
```

I also tried the non-greedy operator and that failed too:

```
(~r/---(.+)---(.+)?.*/s
```

Any suggestions would be super helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I removed the Perl and PCRE tags since they aren't germaine to the question.

Comment: I was looking for a PCRE'ish solution, since I am using Elixir, which has a PCRE regex engine. Hence, the tags.

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.scan` function like below.

```
> str = "---title: Some Title\ndate: 01/01/2012---\n\nSome other stuff---\n\n"
> str.scan(/---([\s\S]+?)---/)[0][0]
=> "title: Some Title\ndate: 01/01/2012"
```

Output of the above scan function is a two dimensional array is because of the existence of capturing group. `[\s\S]+?` Matches one or more space or non-space characters non-greedily. Note that this pattern would also match the line breaks (*`\n`, `\r`*).

Answer (score 0):

A more generic regex is:

```
(?:---)?(?<key>[a-z]+)\s*:\s*(?<value>(?!\\n).+?)(?:\\n|---|$)
```

It splits the match in key:value.

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/X1q7kXlxiM)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a generic solution - i.e. not something that expects title and date to be there. I would like this to work for anything in between the `---(some stuff here)---`.

Answer (score 0):

```
---(?:(?!---).)*---
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/34

Answer (score 0):

The right way here is not to try to match the part you want to extract, but match the part you want to throw away and use `split`.

```
s.split(/---\n*/)
#=> ["", "title: Some Title\ndate: 01/01/2012", "Some other stuff"]

str.split(/---\n*/)[1]
#=> "title: Some Title\ndate: 01/01/2012"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was really looking for a match capture solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you ultimately want the title and date string, you may as well pull them out directly:

```
str.scan(/---title:\s+([^\n]+)\ndate:\s+(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/)
  #=> [["Some Title", "01/01/2012"]]
```

Comment: There's no need for a lookbehind here.  Just match that part the normal way and ignore it, same as you're doing with the `date:` part.

Comment: Thanks, @Alan. I fixed it. A small thing, but removing the lookie also allowed me to change `title:\s` to  `title:\s+`. [Readers: I formerly had `(?<=---title:\s)` is a ("zero-width") "positive lookbehind"].

Answer (score 0):

A perl way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my $str = "---title: Some Title\ndate: 01/01/2012---\n\nSome other stuff---\n\n";
$str =~ s/---(.+?)---.*?$/$1/s;
say $str;
```

**Output:**

```
title: Some Title
date: 01/01/2012
```

Comment: So cool! I knew I had to employ a mix of non-greedy operator, along with some matching across new-lines. I was wondering, why do we need the second "?" before the "$"? Isn't it just enough to have?
`~r/---(.+?)---.*$/s`

Thanks!

Comment: Also, does it have to **not** be greedy? Couldn't I just do, `regex = ~r/---([^-{3}]+)---.*$/s`?